# Angular DI Service - Displaying properties

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a service (Foo) being dependency injected (constuctor) into a number of components. This service has a property (Foo.timeZone). One of the components needs to bind the value of this property to a templates list of timezones - effectively allowing the user to change the timezone and making it available to the other components. What is the best way of binding the foo.timeZone property to the templates selectable list?

1. Public DI and bind directly to property? constructor(**public** myFoo: Foo) { }
2. Public property on component, keep the private DI property and public component property in sync.
3. Something else ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `OnPush`, then it is best to use `Subject`, because using the properties of the public service does not trigger change detection.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paxamw

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimeZoneService {

  private timeZone$ = new BehaviorSubject('America/Adak');

  getTimeZone() {
    return this.timeZone$.asObservable();
  }

  changeTimeZone(timeZone: string) {
    this.timeZone$.next(timeZone)
  }

}
```

```js
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeZoneService } from './time-zone.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <p>{{timeZone$ | async}} <small>Use Subject</small></p>
  `
  ,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  timeZone$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(public timeZoneService: TimeZoneService) {
    this.timeZone$ = this.timeZoneService.getTimeZone()
  }
}
```

Also create an accessor component and then use the template reference variable.

```js
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeZoneService } from './time-zone.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'time-zone-accessor',
  template: ``,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TimeZoneAccessorComponent  {

  timeZone$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(public timeZoneService: TimeZoneService) {
    this.timeZone$ = this.timeZoneService.getTimeZone()
  }
}
```

Use the template reference variable.

```html
<time-zone-accessor #timeZone></time-zone-accessor>
<p>{{timeZone.timeZone$ | async}}</p>
```

Comment: Clean code. Shouldn't `TimeZoneService.timeZone$` variable be private?